# I'm wondering how gapi.signin.render() callback function works

Tags: javascript, api

I want to call gapi.signin.render()'s callback function just once.

```
gapi.signin.render('googleLoginBtn', {
  'callback': 'checkAuth',
  'clientid': clientid,
  'cookiepolicy': 'single_host_origin',
  'scope': scopes
});
```

My full code works properly.
However, the code is calling repeatedly callback function until I actually log in at google.com.
I'm wondering if it's normal or not.